# Edcast + Icecast on AWS Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, audio, icecast, internet-radio

how do I run edcast + icecast on a Windows 2008 Server with no audio device being available on the server to pick in the edcast config? I'm aware that I can't listen to the audio on the server, but shouldn't I be able to stream an audio stream anyway and then listen on my workstations using a browser e.g.?

Regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are dummy audio devices for Windows as software solutions.
You can install one of these and use it as a pipe to link a player to Edcast, which will then stream that to an Icecast mountpoint.

CF. E.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Audio_Cable

Comment: That worked perfectly (I already had the windows audio services enabled)! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is enable the Windows Audio service.  Go to 'Services', find 'Windows Audio', start it, and set 'Startup Type' to 'Automatic'.  You'll end up with a speaker icon on your systray, but it will have an error for now as there is no sound device.

As @TBR suggested, the next step is to install a loopback audio driver which enables you to play audio out of one application and record it on another.  This driver appears as a normal sound device, but is just software.  There are [several to choose from](https://superuser.com/q/356536/48624).  I've had good luck with the [VB-Cable](https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/), which is available as donationware.

Once that's set up, your audio software should be able to play back, and Edcast should be able to record.